# Can anyone tell me How to get the API key for Emporia vue gen 2?

Tags: java

I want to connect Emporia device with my Java API. Now I need the Emporia API key to do that. Can anyone tell me How to get the Emporia API key? I've already done registration through their app, but there needs to be an option for getting an API key. Please help me to find it out.

I want to solution for finding the API key

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://emporia-connect.xyt.co.za

It is a free 3rd party API for emporia vue

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: No affiliation. It's a free service